# A space walls $(S,M)$ is discrete if and only if $M$ is locally finite?

Tags: geometric-group-theory

A space with walls is simple a set a pair $(S,M)$ is simply a set $S$ together with a collection of subsets $M$ closed under complementation. A space with walls clearly forms a pocset under inclusion. $A < B$ implies $B^* < A^*$.

A pocset is a poset $M$ together with an order reversing involution $A\to A^*$ such that $A\not= A^*$, $A$ and $A^*$ are incomparable

A pocset is said to be locally finite if every interval is finite, i.e. if $A<B$ then $\{C|A<C<B\}$ is a finite set.

A space with walls clearly forms a pocset under inclusion. It is said to be discrete if for any two elements of $a, b \in S$ the collection of subsets in $M$ containing $a$ and not containing $b$ is finite.

Is that true $(S,M)$ is discrete if and only if $M$ is locally finite?

Comment: @bof you just gave a sketch and I don't know if it's wrong or correct. And your former answer which you deleted was wrong. If you give more details then I would like to go through the details

Comment: @bof you can post a question using proof-verification to ask people to check your solution.

Comment: Usually "space of walls" requires the condition that for every $x,y$, $\{A\in M:x\in A,y\notin A\}$ is finite. But fine, you call it "discrete space with walls".

Comment: The accepted answer gives a locally finite, not discrete example. Here's a discrete, not locally finite: on $\mathbf{Z}$ consider all unbounded intervals. It is discrete (there are exactly $|m-n|$ unbounded intervals containing $m$ and not $n$) but not locally finite since $[\emptyset,\mathbf{Z}]$ is infinite.

Comment: Also for $S$ infinite, taking $M$ as the set of subsets of cardinal 3 and their complements  gives a "space of walls" (in the given sense) for which each interval $[A,B]$ with $A<B$ is reduced to $\{A,B\}$, hence is "locally finite" but not "discrete". (Another example of the failure of the same implication was given as an answer by user "bof" and was accepted then unaccepted.)

Comment: @YCor I think your $M$ is not just unbounded intervals but also $\emptyset$ since we require $M$ to be closed under complementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to be a counterexample. What am I missing?

Let $S$ be the set of all periodic functions $\sigma:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$.

For $x,y\in\mathbb Z$, let
$L_{x,y}=\{\sigma\in S:\sigma(x)\le y\}$ and
$U_{x,y}=\{\sigma\in S:\sigma(x)\ge y\}$.

Let $M=\{L_{x,y}:x,y\in\mathbb Z\}\cup\{U_{x,y}:x,y\in\mathbb Z\}$.

Then $(S,M)$ is a space with walls, and $M$ is locally finite, but $(S,M)$ is not discrete.

**$(S,M)$ is a space with walls.**

The definition requires $M$ to be closed under complementation. The complement of $L_{x,y}$ is $U_{x,y+1}$, and the complement of $U_{x,y}$ is $L_{x.y-1}$.

**$M$ is locally finite.**

Suppose $A,B\in M$ and $A\lt B$. There are two cases.

Case 1. $A=L_{x,y}$ and $B=L_{x,z}$ where $y\lt z$. Then
$\{C:A\lt C\lt B\}=\{L_{x,w}:y\lt w\lt z\}$ is finite.

Case 2. $A=U_{x,y}$ and $B=U_{x,z}$ where $y\gt z$. Then
$\{C:A\lt C\lt B\}=\{U_{x,w}:y\gt w\gt z\}$ is finite.

**$(S,M)$ is not discrete.**

Suppose $\sigma_1,\sigma_2\in S$ and $\sigma_1\ne\sigma_2$. Let $\sigma_i$ be periodic with period $p_i\gt0$; then both $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ are periodic with period $p=p_1p_2$. Choose $x\in\mathbb Z$ with $\sigma_1(x)\ne\sigma_2(x)$ and let $y_1=\sigma_1(x)$ and $y_2=\sigma_2(x)$. Then $\sigma_1(x+np)=y_1$ and $\sigma_2(x+np)=y_2$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$. let
$$A_n=\begin{cases}
L_{x+np,y_1}\text{ if }y_1\lt y_2,\\
U_{x+np,y_1}\text{ if }y_1\gt y_2.
\end{cases}$$
Then $\sigma_1\in A_n$ but $\sigma_2\notin A_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$.